Unique weak solution of an SDE for a general initial distribution
$
\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\bT}{\mathbb{T}}
\newcommand{\bP}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\bF}{\mathbb{F}}
\newcommand{\cF}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
$
We fix $T \in (0, \infty)$ and let $\bT$ be the interval $[0, T]$. We consider measurable functions
\begin{align}
b &: \bT \times \bR^d \to \bR^d, \\
\sigma &: \bT \times \bR^d \to \bR^d \otimes \bR^m.
\end{align}
Let $(B_t, t \ge 0)$ be a $m$-dimensional Brownian motion and $\bF := (\cF_t, t \ge 0)$ an admissible filtration on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal A, \bP)$. We consider the SDE
\begin{equation} \tag{1}\label{1}
\diff X_t = b(t, X_t) \diff t + \sigma(t, X_t) \diff B_t,
\quad t \in \bT,
\end{equation}
where the distribution of $X_0$ is $\nu$. Let $a := \sigma \sigma^\top$. We assume that there exist constants $C > 0, \beta \in (0, 1)$ such that for $t \in \bT$ and $x, y \in \bR^d$:

$\nu$ has finite first-moment and $a(t, x)$ is invertible.
The following inequalities hold:
\begin{align}
|b(t, x)|  + | \sigma (t, x) | + | a^{-1} (t, x) | &\le C, \\
|\sigma (t, x) - \sigma (t, y)| &\le C |x-y|^{\beta}. 
\end{align}

It is well-known that if $\nu = \delta_x$ for some $x \in \bR^d$, then \eqref{1} has a unique weak solution. See this paper for instance.

Is it true that \eqref{1} has a unique weak solution for $\nu$ that is not necessarily a Dirac measure?

Thank you for your elaboration.

Yes via the martingale problem formulation, and you can read about it e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2614302/initial-distribution-of-stochastic-differential-equations

@unwissen Thank you very much for your enlightening comment which completely solves my problem.
